# Alleviate long qualifications in header files

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17, header-files, using

I define an `inline` function object in a header file, like this:

```cpp
// fmap.hpp
namespace util {
    inline auto constexpr fmap = boost::hana::curry<2>(boost::hana::flip(boost::hana::transform));
}
```

Client code can simply `#include "fmap.hpp"` and start using `util::fmap` as they like.

So far so good.

But sometimes the definition of such objects can be cumbersome to read, if they are so full of `qui::quo::qua::lify`.

How can I alleviate this?

Ideally, I'd like the definition of `fmap` to look like this:

```cpp
namespace util {
    inline auto constexpr fmap = curry<2>(flip(transform));
}
```

but at the same time I don't want to put a `using namespace boost::hana;` at top level, as [client code's namespace would be cluttered with `boost::hana`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69183293/5825294) (or from other namespaces) names, not to mention that [some compilers have hard time with `using namespace` directives in generic lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221487/msvc-using-namespace-directive-in-caller-of-generic-lambda-leaks-into-the-lamb).

Is there some C++ guideline or best practice that comes handy in this situation?

Comment: If you don't want to clutter up your global or `util` namespaces, you could create a nested namespace `util::helper` (or some such) where you could be `using namespace whatever;` and declare all kinds of helper types, which are then used by the symbols in the `util` namespace.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes, I don't want to clutter [...]. But I haven't understood fully your suggestion. Would I have to put `fmap` declaration too into `helper` and then, back in `util` I'd do `using helper::fmap` so that clients would see `util::fmap`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your definition. It is simple, and easy to understand. Maybe just split it into two lines.

Comment: That's an opinion. For me it takes longer to understand what's written with all those `::`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about it, I can solve the riddle by just constructing and calling on the fly a lambda from `void` (hence the `()` between `[]` and `{}` can be removed) to the desired lambda:

```cpp
namespace utils {

inline auto constexpr fmap = []{
    using namespace boost::hana;
    return curry<2>(flip(transform));
}();

}
```