# About using directives in namespace in header files

Tags: c++, include, header-files, ambiguous, cpp-core-guidelines

(This is kind of related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69158170/alleviate-long-qualifications-in-header-files/69182472#69182472).)

Core guideline [SF.7](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-using-directive) gives a good motivation for avoiding to put `using namespace` directives at global scope in a header file.

However, even writing `using namespace` in a non-global namespace can be problematic. For example:

- `header1.hpp`

  ```cpp
  #include <boost/hana/transform.hpp>
  namespace ab {
      using namespace boost::hana;
      inline constexpr auto a = transform;
  }
  ```
- `header2.hpp`

  ```cpp
  #include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
  namespace ab {
      using namespace ranges::views;
      inline constexpr auto b = transform;
  }
  ```
- `main.cpp`

  ```
  #include "header1.hpp"
  #include "header2.hpp"
  // here ab::b is ambiguous
  int main() {
  }
  ```

  with error (from clang)

  ```
  In included file: reference to 'transform' is ambiguous
  /home/enrico/header2.hpp:4:31:
  note: error occurred here
  /usr/include/boost/hana/fwd/transform.hpp:53:27:
  note: candidate found by name lookup is 'boost::hana::transform'
  :567:46:
  note: candidate found by name lookup is 'ranges::views::transform'
  ```

Is there a reason why the guidelines don't mention this?

Should we entirely avoid `using namespace n;`/`using n::x;`/`namespace n = m;` at namespace scope?

---

## Related

In [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69158170/5825294) I have self-answerd with a way to use those directives when defining an object in a header file, but without cluttering anything, by wrapping all RHS of assignment in a `void`-to-`desired-object` lambda called in place.

Comment: Yes avoid using namespace in header files period. They become painful very quickly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice. I think what you describe is just another version of the same guideline.

Comment: Why would `ab::b` be ambiguous?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, because both `boost::hana::transform` and `ranges::views::transform` can take 2 arguments.

Comment: Since namespace aliases are a thing, IMHO there is no reason to use `using namespace ...;`.  Sure there is some more type involved, but avoiding name conflicts is worth it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I've added the error.

Comment: Possibly related: [scope of using declaration within a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175705/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks, that answers my question!